# How to find elements inside Ajax:Page?

Tags: ajax, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm navigating a webpage that is basically fully loaded by an ajax call, and I've included the corresponding wait:

`self._wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)`

The page consists only of some tables and buttons, but I can't find any of them with Selenium. I've tried every find_element() combination but nothing works.

I tried getting the html source from the page:

`html = self.driver.page_source`

but the only thing I get is:

```
<html><head></head><frameset cols="*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
    <frame name="MAIN" src="main.jsp">
</frameset></html>
```

though when I inspect it, there's a lot contained inside `<ajax:page>`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a frameset, so you have to switch the driver to the relevant frame.  Use webdriverwait with ExpectedCondition, "FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt".

Answer (score 1):

You need to know something about why and how to switch into iframe.

such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python) and [this url](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)